# what is wrong? please see the below coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Person/

      //string fname { get; set; }
      //string lname { get;  set; }

        public string  Index()
        {

          return "This is the first";

        }

        public string welcome()
        {
            return "welcome";

        }

    }
}
```

i have created a personcontroller and wrote the above coding. when i run the program it alwasy give the asp.net mvc2 default page. how can i set my personcontroller as my start page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the routes in your Global.asax.cs.  You will need a route like this if you want the index action to the be the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Web.Default",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Person", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

If you want the default action to be `welcome` then you can use this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Web.Default",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Person", action = "welcome", id = "" });
```